# Decomposition of supermartingale into UI martingale and supermartingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I am trying to prove the following ([source](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/sites/www.maths.cam.ac.uk/files/pre2014/postgrad/mathiii/pastpapers/2006/Paper32.pdf), Question 1(b)):

> Let $X_n$ be a $L^1$ bounded supermartingale. Then show that there are
>   $M,Y$ s.t.
>
> - $X_n=M_n+Y_n$
> - $M$ is a uniformly integrable martingale
> - $Y$ is a supermartingale converging to 0 almost surely

The question it comes from has previous parts outlining the decomposition of a submartingale into a martingale and an $L^1$ bounded supermartingale. I am not sure if that this previous result is useful here, since we now want the integrability condition on the martingale, not the supermartingale. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start: The $L^1$ bounded supermartingale $X_n$ has an a.s. limit $X_\infty$, and the r.v. $X_\infty$ is integrable, by Fatou. Define $M_n:=\Bbb E[X_\infty|\mathcal F_n]$. Show that if $Y_n:=X_n-M_n$ then $Y_n$ is a supermartingale.

Comment: Ah thank you! Did not notice that the a.s. limit would also be integrable but now makes sense.